# “resizable” set to false is not disabling the maximize button in iced 0.10.0 but was working in earlier versions

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

The `resizable` data member of the **iced library** struct `iced::window::Settings` struct when set to *false* is not disabling the minimize button in the menu bar in the latest **iced 0.10.0** version.

**Success Case:**
It was working as expected in the older versions of iced till iced 0.9.0.

This the screen shot of progress example built with iced 0.9.0. Here the maximize button is disable when the resizable was set to false:

[image]

**Failure Case:**
This the screen shot of progress example built with iced 0.10.0. Here the maximize button is still enabled even if the resizable is set to false:

[image]

Here’s the code snippet to reproduce and test the behavior:

```
use iced::window;
use iced::settings::Settings;
use iced::{Element, Sandbox};
use iced::widget::{column, progress_bar, slider};

pub fn main() -> iced::Result {
    Progress::run(Settings{
         window: iced::window::Settings 
         { 
                    resizable: false,
                    ..window::Settings::default()
             },
             ..Settings::default()
         }
    )
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Progress {
    value: f32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum Message {
    SliderChanged(f32),
}

impl Sandbox for Progress {
    type Message = Message;

    fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("A simple Progressbar")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, message: Message) {
        match message {
            Message::SliderChanged(x) => self.value = x,
        }
    }

    fn view(&self) -> Element<Message> {
        column![
            progress_bar(0.0..=100.0, self.value),
            slider(0.0..=100.0, self.value, Message::SliderChanged).step(0.01)
        ]
        .padding(20)
        .into()
    }
}
```

Can anyone help how to solve this problem on priority as this is blocking our product release.

Comment: Maybe you should raise a bug on the iced repo

Comment: It seems like the resizable property of the iced::window::Settings struct is not behaving as expected in the latest version of the iced library (0.10.0). If it's a known bug in the library, the best approach would be to report it to the library's maintainers or check if someone has already reported it. In the meantime, here are some potential steps you can take to troubleshoot or mitigate the problem:

Revert to an Older Version: If this feature is crucial for your product and was working a can you share the repository link so i work on it from my end to resolve the issue?